# Max Size of Disks Supported by Controller

Tags: raid, storage, hard-drive, dell

I am interested in purchasing (second hand) a Dell Poweredge 2950 2nd Gen server. However, the specs say it has a max storage size of 4.5tb. I am wondering if this means just what is available to install from the factory, or if it is a limitation of the controller?

If it is relevant, I do not want to boot from these drives, simply use it as storage e.g. I would like to run RAID 10 with either four sata 2tb or four sata 3tb disks. I would also (despite having the PERC controller) run software RAID.

Specifications: http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/2950_specs.pdf

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spec indicates the max size possible using Dell proprietary disks offered for that server at the time, so it is largely irrelevant.

The actual limit is 2TB per disk for the Perc5 (and many other controllers) but there is nothing stopping you from using a newer raid controller that supports bigger disks. An H700 for example is not supported but will work perfectly well. (I would also advise using at least NL-SAS over SATA)

Another thing to bear in mind is that the 2950 comes in several variations of drives 8x2.5", 6x3.5" or only 4x3.5" if it has the tapedrive bay.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am really just planning to use for an (admittedly) fairly beefy home server. Do you really think NL-SAS are necessary?

Comment: Its not vital but there is an overhead of upto 20% for tunneling SATA.